# Matrix multiplication error or is it just me?

Tags: matrix-calculus, svd

I was reading a bit on SVD and ran into this "error"

http://web.mit.edu/be.400/www/SVD/Singular_Value_Decomposition.htm

[image: Isn't this an error?]

Comment: The only problem is that $A^T$ is copied down incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A^T $ is a typo. $W $ is correct, though.

Comment: corrected version:  \begin{equation}
 AA^T = \begin{bmatrix}
  2&4\\
 1&3\\
 0&0\\
 0&0
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
 2&1&0&0\\
 4&3&0&0
 \end{bmatrix}
 =
 \begin{bmatrix}
 2 \cdot 2  + 4 \cdot 4 &  2 \cdot 1  + 4 \cdot 3 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 \cdot 2  + 3 \cdot 4 &  1 \cdot 1  + 3 \cdot 3 & 0 & 0 \\
 0&0&0&0\\
 0&0&0&0
 \end{bmatrix}
 =
  \begin{bmatrix}
20 & 14 & 0 & 0 \\
14 &  10& 0 & 0 \\
 0&0&0&0\\
 0&0&0&0
 \end{bmatrix}=W
 \end{equation}